Why does alembic only put one migration version in it's table?
I am setting up alembic in a new project.
I successfully got the first migration working in my local and aws postgres databases. Added 5 tables.
I noticed that when I ran a second migration, only the new migration version shows up in the alembic version table...
Does Alembic write ONLY the latest migration file's version number to the database? How do I then track what has or hasn't happened in terms of migrations in that specific database?  Am I misunderstanding the "pattern" here?  Every other tool I've used writes a row for every migration - alembic did not do this for me.
